# HTML image source mysterious behaviour

Tags: html, image

So I have multiple `<img>` tags in a page. When I set their source to something random, they show up correctly, but when I feed them some specific URLs, for example:

http://img1.prosperent.com/images/250x250/www.modernbathroom.com/images-cache/5E/2E/952F/5E2E952F79551F7CAB26E129CBEB28BBD7176DF0.jpg

images just disappear (they have fixed width and height from CSS file) and some mysterious attributes automatically are added:

```
<img src="http://img1.prosperent.com/images/250x250/www.modernbathroom.com/images-cache/5E/2E/952F/5E2E952F79551F7CAB26E129CBEB28BBD7176DF0.jpg" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;">
```

Original `img` doesn't have any inline stylings and there is no any JS script running in the page. The question is why that is happening, whether remote image can force image tag to have some attributes and how to prevent that.

Comment: How are you setting their source?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle Page is dynamically generated using PHP, I feed them from array received from external source.

Comment: Is there a part of the executing PHP script that looks for `img` tags and rewrites them?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle No, here is the `img` tag when viewing from source code: `<img src="http://img1.prosperent.com/images/250x250/www.modernbathroom.com/images-cache/5E/58/0727/5E5807273DDB54B357BB80DE3D5BDF669CA8C4CA.jpg" />` so that attributes are added dynamically after page is loaded.

Comment: are you using any browser add-ons that might effect images? Like hover-zoom?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle You got it! Thank you very much, actually Chrome AdBlocker was blocking them. Please post your last comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are using a browser extension that is re-writing certain image tags?

Try completely disabling all browser extensions and javascript and see if it still happens.